# add only one value to a picklist target (PrimeFaces)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a search function which searches the system. After performing search I am updating the search result in to pick List. Each Time I search I will update pickList source. Now My problem is I want to validate in such a way that if more than 1 value is added to the pick list target It should give me error message and also check about the duplicate entries in picklist target.

Below is the code of picklist in xhmtl

```
    <p:pickList id="primaryContactBean" value="#{addSystemManagedBean.primaryContactList}" var="contact" itemLabel="#{contact.firstName}" itemValue="#{contact}" converter="contactConverter" >
   <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{addSystemManagedBean.onTransfer}" process="@this"          update="sysMsg3" />
  <p:column>
     #{contact.firstName} #{contact.lastName}
   </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

and onTransfer the following method gets called

```
public int primaryOwnerCount = 0;
    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        PickList picklist = (PickList) event.getComponent();
            for(Object item : event.getItems()) {  
                ContactBean cb = (ContactBean)item;
                if(picklist.getId().equals("primaryContactBean")){
                    if(event.isAdd())
                    primaryOwnerCount++;
                    if(primaryOwnerCount>1){
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Only one primary owner can exist!!","If you want to add owner, please remove from the list and then proceed.."));
                        for (Iterator iterator = primaryContactList.getTarget().iterator(); iterator
                                .hasNext();) {
                            ContactBean type = (ContactBean) iterator.next();
                            System.out.println("target:"+type.getFirstName());
                        }


                    }

                    else
                        primaryContactTarget.add(cb);
                }
```

Comment: I'm not experienced JSF/primefaces user but I can say that you can use `validator`/`validatorMessage` to do this. More information about this you can find here http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/ and on java ee tutorial. I think that you can also create `ManagedBean` which will work as validator.

Comment: If your requirement is to allow selection of only one item, why dont you use listbox instead of picklist ?

Comment: i want the drag and drop effect so i have used picklist